# Socket Programming with stream sockets over local area network

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, lan

I am learning inter-process communication. I want to create server that can listen to client distributed over actual local area network. I have IP address as well as symbolic name of those machines. I can implement sever and client on single machine but I don't know how to do same on different machines on network.
   Can anyone direct me to appropriate resources or tell me how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same. The only difference is that you need to use the server ip address instead of the local address when you connect the client socket.

Comment: @ Klas: To create socket we use new socket(url,port) so do I have to just change url by ip address of that machine ?

Comment: @SumitLonkar no we don't use `new socket(url,port)`. I suggest you read the Javadoc before posting again.

Comment: how do you get that ip address?